# Adding <start> and <end> tokens to lines of a tokenized document

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

Apologies if I'm making an extremely trivial mistake! Essentially, I have a tokenized, downloaded document (which I tokenized the normal way using NLTK, i.e. `tokens = word_tokenize(f.read())`, meaning `tokens` is a list). I want to add start and end tokens to the start and end of each line. I also have a dictionary `vocab` which does what it sounds like (stores each word in the document).

The two things I have tried are:

```
for line in tokens:
    line.insert(0,'<start>')
    line.insert(len(line)-1,'<end>')
    vocab['<start>']+=1
    vocab['<end>']+=1
```

and:

```
for line in tokens:
    line=['<start>']+line+['<end>']
    vocab['<start>']+=1
    vocab['<end>']+=1
```

If I use the .insert() method, I get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'insert'`. If I try to concatenate the start/end tokens to every line in the tokens list, I get `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list.` Not really sure how to fix this so I'd appreciate any help :)

Comment: As tokens is a list of string, and if you loop through a list, each element would be a string -- not a list. In your case, 'line' is a string, so you cannot do an insert on a string as insert only works for List object.

Comment: @CodeJonSnow so surely the second method should work, right?

Comment: you have to use same data types to concatenate using '+'. the issue of your second method is you are concatenate a list (['<start>']), a string (line) and another list (['<end>']) together, but they are not the same type. You can use line = '<start>' + line + '<end>' instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
for i in range(len(tokens)):
    tokens[i] = '<start>' + tokens[i] + '<end>'
    vocab['<start>']+=1
    vocab['<end>']+=1
```

basically what this does is to loop through each line and add start and end token to each line. Using range(len(tokens)), you can directly change element's value in tokens.

Comment: Doesn't this just add the token to the start of tokens and not to every line? Also it now tells me that 'line' is undefined

Comment: okay I editted the answer to meet your requirement.